# Is "whatever you say, do" an accurate translation of "quodcumque dixerit facite"?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation, vulgata

**Background:**

The Latin phrase,

> quodcumque dixerit vobis facite,

taken from John 2:5 of the Vulgate, translates to,

> Whatsoever he shall say to you, do ye,

according to the Douay-Rheims translation of the Vulgate (http://vulgate.org/nt/gospel/john_2.htm), or,

> do whatever he tells you,

according to Yandex (https://translate.yandex.com/?lang=la-en&text=quodcumque%20dixerit%20vobis%20facite).

However, sometimes a shortened version of this phrase is used, where the word "vobis" is removed, i.e.,

> quodcumque dixerit facite.

See, for example, the coat of arms of Seán Patrick O'Malley: https://www.heraldry-wiki.com/heraldrywiki/index.php?title=Se%C3%A1n_Patrick_O%27Malley.

According to https://www.heraldry-wiki.com/heraldrywiki/index.php?title=Quodcumque_dixerit_facite, the shortened phrase "quodcumque dixerit facite", translates to

> whatever you say, do.

(this translation also agrees with Yandex https://translate.yandex.com/?lang=la-en&text=quodcumque%20dixerit%20facite and Google https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=quodcumque%20dixerit%C2%A0facite) However, this translation does not quite make sense to me as "dixerit" in Latin is third person singular, so I am not sure where the "you" comes from in "whatever you say, do."

> Therefore, what is the correct English translation of "quodcumque dixerit facite"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct! The verb is still third person singular, and should be translated that way.

To make it painfully literal, the verb is future perfect, so:

> Whatever (s)he will have said, all of you, do it.

Or, for actually good English:

> Everyone, do whatever (s)he says.

*Vobis* just specifies that the speaker is saying these things "to all of you"; without it, though, it's still quite clear that "he" is speaking, not "you".

Comment: Sorry, I've got a fixation about Latin ambiguities. How do you know it's not perfect subjunctive, indirect after *quodcumque?*

Comment: @Hugh Could also be that, "whatever he might have said", but the subjunctive feels a bit weird to me here

Comment: @Hugh: It is my understanding that the perfect subjunctive is only used in specific circumstances e.g. (i) conditional sentences (improbable conditions); if the conditional act is completed before the consequence begins the perfect subjunctive is used, instead of present subjunctive; (ii) "cum" = since/ because (cum librum legerim = since I have read the book); consecutive clauses; perf. subj. can be used after a historic tense; but, only (a) when the result is momentary, not continuous and (b) the result actually did follow (tantus erat ardor militum ut nemo motum terrae senserit

Comment: @Hugh: Continuing: …= the soldiers were so engrossed that no one felt the earthquake); (iii) prohibition e.g. ne + second-person of the perfect subjunctive (ne feceris illud, Marce! = Don't do that, Marcus!). I used to wonder what the perf. subj. was for, so I compiled a list of its uses; but, this may not be exhaustive.

Comment: @Draconis: If a subjunctive was used here would it not have to be imperfect--"diceret" = "he might have said"; definitely not perfect subj?

Comment: @tony That's probably it! All I can say for certain is that a perfect subjunctive here feels wrong to me for unclear reasons, but you articulated it much better.